# Why parameters did not applied in api request?

Tags: python, rest

I'm trying to get some data with bitfinex rest api but parameters doesn't applying and I get incorrect data. Could somebody tell me what wrong?

```
import requests
import json

URL = 'https://api.bitfinex.com/v2/trades/tBTCUSD/hist'
params = {
    'start': 1482400030,  # I expect to get piece of data starting from this timestamp
    'limit': 1000,
          }

response = requests.get(URL, params=json.dumps(params))
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried making sure that json.dumps(params) is giving the output you're expecting?  It could be malformed and getting ignored by the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whats the purpose of `params=json.dumps(params)`?

`response = requests.get(URL, params=params)` works fine

`json.dumps` inserts unnecessary double quotes

check below the difference:

```
>>> json.dumps(params)
'{"start": 1482400030, "limit": 1000}'
>>> response = requests.get(URL, params=json.dumps(params))
>>> response.url
u'https://api.bitfinex.com/v2/trades/tBTCUSD/hist?%7B%22start%22:%201482400030,%20%22limit%22:%201000%7D'
>>> response = requests.get(URL, params=params)
>>> response.url
u'https://api.bitfinex.com/v2/trades/tBTCUSD/hist?start=1482400030&limit=1000'
```